# Div with max width, in case 1 child, also in case 2 childs or 3 childs, with flex

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have a parent div, that at least contains one child. In some cases it will contain 2 children and in the last case it will contain 3 children.
I would like to achieve that in all three cases the children expand to the 100% width.

Case1
Here **childrenA** should be width:100%

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childrenA"></div>
</div>
```

Case2
Here **childrenA** should be width:50% and **childrenB** should be width:50%

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childrenA"></div>
  <div class="childrenB"></div>
</div>
```

Case3
Here **childrenA** should be width:33%, **childrenB** should be width:33% and **childrenC** should be width:33%

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childrenA"></div>
  <div class="childrenB"></div>
  <div class="childrenC"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah width can be set automatically with the help of flex box assuming the height of the child elements is specified;

on Parent div

```
 .parent {
  display:flex;
 }
```

assuming the height of children divs to be 100px,we can do

```
 .childrenA{
  background-color:violet;
  height:100px;
  flex:1;
}

.childrenB{
  background-color:grey;
  height:100px;
  flex:1;
}

.childrenC{
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
  flex:1;
}
```

flex:1 is a shorthand for

```
 flex-grow : 1;    ➜ The div will grow in same proportion as the window-size       
flex-shrink : 1;  ➜ The div will shrink in same proportion as the window-size 
flex-basis : 0;   ➜ The div does not have a starting value as such and will 
                     take up screen as per the screen size available for
                     e.g:- if 3 divs are in the wrapper then each div will take 33%.
```

```css
.childrenA {
  background-color: violet;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.childrenB {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.childrenC {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childrenA"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="childrenA"></div>
  <div class="childrenB"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="childrenA"></div>
  <div class="childrenB"></div>
  <div class="childrenC"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know the main question is solved, thank you. But in case I would like to force childrenC to go to a new row (for example in small screens) how could I achieve it? I know I need to use the media queries